# Issues with breaking a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, break

So I'm trying to create a program that iterates through  2D array until it finds a matching ticket; however when the program finds the number within the array it doesn't break:

```
    var namesArray = ["Reece", "Jack", "Lewis", "Ryan"];

    var raffleArray = [
      [193, 109, 97, 479],
      [489, 046, 387, 830],
      [475, 947, 294, 590],
      [330, 395, 750, 649]
    ];

    //function getRandomNum(){
    //  return Math,floor(Math.random() * (999 - ))
    //}

    //loops through the 2D array to search for 
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      for (i = 0; i < raffleArray[j].length; i++) {
        if (raffleArray[j][i] == 294) { //294 is only set for testing
          alert(namesArray[j] + " has won the raffle with ticket number:         " + raffleArray[j][i]);
          break;
        } else {
          alert("Ticket: " + raffleArray[j][i]+ " did not win"} //only for testing
      }
    }}
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Break will only break your inner for loop..

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)` `namesArray`has only 4 members, so shouldn't it be `j < 4`, or even better `j < namesArray.length`?

Comment: Also your  `j < 5` is wrong,.. There are only 4 elements..  maybe do  `j < namesArray.length`

Answer (score 4):

You need to label the outer loop to break out of both.

```
  search:for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < raffleArray[j].length; i++) {
      if (raffleArray[j][i] == 294) { //294 is only set for testing
        alert(namesArray[j] + " has won the raffle with ticket number:         " + raffleArray[j][i]);
        break search;
      }
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a boolean variable to find the required element is matched or not. once it is found break inner loop. where you have to assign true to boolean variable. if boolean var is true then break outer loop.

```
var isFound = false;

   //loops through the 2D array to search for 
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      for (i = 0; i < raffleArray[j].length; i++) {
        if (raffleArray[j][i] == 294) { //294 is only set for testing
            found = true;
          alert(namesArray[j] + " has won the raffle with ticket number:         " + raffleArray[j][i]);
          break;
        } else {
          alert("Ticket: " + raffleArray[j][i]+ " did not win"} //only for testing
      }
      if(isFound) {
        break;
      }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary variable to break the outer loop as:

```
    var found = false;

   //loops through the 2D array to search for 
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      for (i = 0; i < raffleArray[j].length; i++) {
        if (raffleArray[j][i] == 294) { //294 is only set for testing
            found = true;
          alert(namesArray[j] + " has won the raffle with ticket number:         " + raffleArray[j][i]);
          break;
        } else {
          alert("Ticket: " + raffleArray[j][i]+ " did not win"} //only for testing
      }
      if(found) {
        break;
      }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a flag to stop the outer loop.

```
var namesArray = ["Reece", "Jack", "Lewis", "Ryan"];

var raffleArray = [
    [193, 109, 97, 479],
    [489, 046, 387, 830],
    [475, 947, 294, 590, 294],
    [330, 395, 750, 649]
];

//function getRandomNum(){
//  return Math,floor(Math.random() * (999 - ))
//}

//loops through the 2D array to search for
var winner = false;
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  if(!winner) {
    for (i = 0; i < raffleArray[j].length; i++) {
        if (raffleArray[j][i] == 294) { 
            //294 is only set for testing
            winner = true;
            alert(namesArray[j] + " has won the raffle with ticket number:         " + raffleArray[j][i]);
            break;
        } else {
            alert("Ticket: " + raffleArray[j][i] + " did not win")
        }
    }
  }
}
```